# READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT on SQL Server 2005 in 2000 Compatability Mode?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, backwards-compatibility, isolation-level, read-committed-snapshot

While investigating a problem I believed to be related to lock escalation and thinking that READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT would be the solution, I checked whether it was already enabled.  To my surprise, the database had compatibility level 80 (SQL Server 2000, and I'm new here, and nobody or document seems to know why!).

But READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT was new in 2005. So even though it's enabled, does it have any affect when running in 2000 compatibility mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compatibility mode refers to features available in the backaward mode. Any new feature will run unaffected. For instance you can set the compatibility mode to 80 and have the old outer join syntax, but at the same time you can create a Service Broker queue and it will run just fine.

Snapshot isolation is a new feature and works in backward compatible databases unaffacted.

Comment: Thanks for that.

I've also came across these views which show me that the row versioning seems to be taking place:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175492%28SQL.90%29.aspx